# How can i call register next step handler in class base with different class or module in telebot?

Tags: python, class, handler, telebot

How to handle register next_step_handler with new module file in call register next step handler work in telebot ? This is my code.

```
class AgencyBot:
    def __init__(self, agency_name):
        self.agency_name = agency_name


@bot.message_handler(commands=['agency'])
def agency_welcome(self, message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, AgencyMessages.AGENCY_WELLCOME)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, self.agency_number_step)
    

def agency_name_step(self, message):
    print("inside")
    try:
        print("insidr tru")
        new_name = TravelValidation.name_validate(message.text.capitalize())
        user = AgencyBot(new_name)
        user_dict[message.chat.id] = user
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, AgencyMessages.AGENCY_NAME_STEP)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, self.agency_number_step)
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(
            dict(
                message="agency_name_step error ",
                class_name="agency_name_step",
                errors=e,
            )
        )
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, e)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, self.agency_name_step)
        return
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am facing issue while creating different class and i am not able to call a register next step handler in telebot when i create with class base with function base it is working properly so can you suggest me what i can do